# python RuntimeError: "mi" not found for replace

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a date into oracle DB

```
sql = """INSERT INTO app_mobile_scout
    (type_event, date_event, version_app, UUID, name_event, description, device_model, IMEI, ip_device).
    values ('%s', to_date('%s', "yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss"), '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"""%(type_event, date_event, version_app, UUID, name_event, description, device_mod
    res = cur.execute(sql)
```

And I have a error:

```
RuntimeError: "mi" not found for replace in "INSERT INTO app_mobile
    (type_event, date_event, version_app, UUID, name_event, description, device_model, IMEI, ip_device).
    values ('2', to_date('2017/03/16 11:46:06', "yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss"), '4.0.4',......
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can start with not using string formatting to create your SQL statement.  It opens you up to an SQL injection attack.  It's not much of a FAQ, but it's shows what you should do: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq.  Also, some databases treat quotes differently than Python, and Oracle appears to be one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in SQL you should [use single quotes for strings. Double quotes are for identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992403/224671).

```
values ('%s', to_date('%s', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
#                           ^                     ^
```

Also your code is [prone to SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). [Bind variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci04sql.htm#420203) instead:

```
# Note: Doesn't work yet.
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO app_mobile_scout (
        type_event, 
        date_event, 
        version_app, 
        -- etc
    ) VALUES (
        :type,     -- <-- use the variable 'type' here.
        to_date(:date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),
        :version,
        -- etc
    );
""", {
    'type': type_event,    # <-- bind `type_event` to the variable 'type'
    'date': date_event,
    'version': version,
    # etc.
})
```

Now, for some unknown reason the Oracle database is interpreting the `:MI` and `:SS` inside a *string* as placeholders, causing the error seen by OP. I think this is a bug in the Oracle side. As confirmed by OP, it seems can be worked-around by "escaping" the colon by doubling it

```
        to_date(:date, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24::MI::SS'),
```

Comment: RuntimeError: "MI" not found for replace in "INSERT INTO app_mobile
    (type_event, date_event, version_app, UUID, name_event, description, device_model, IMEI, ip_device).
    values (:type_event, to_date(:date_event, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), :version_app, :UUID, :name_event, :description, :device_model, :IMEI, :ip_device)". Must be one of ['version_app', 'date_event', 'IMEI', 'UUID', 'device_model', 'description', 'ip_device', 'name_event', 'type_event']

Comment: @Rainmaker Looks like a problem of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342642/oracle-pl-sql-how-to-escape-colon-being-misinterpreted-for-bind-variable. I don't have an Oracle DB to test now, but what if you tried `HH24::MI::SS` or `HH24\\:MI\\:SS`?

Comment: @Rainmaker OK updated. But I think it is a bug in the Oracle software. Have you tried updating them?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Python, Oracle DB does not interpret single quote `'` like double quote `"`.

In your case, the date format is written between double quote, which is wrong.

In other words, change:

`[...], to_date('2017/03/16 11:46:06', "yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss"), [...]`

to

`[...], to_date('2017/03/16 11:46:06', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), [...]`

---

About single quote vs double quote in Oracle DB:
https://community.oracle.com/message/3853568#3853568

Comment: I changed it to to_date('2017/03/16 11:46:06', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), but result is the same

Comment: Could you update you post adding this new attempt + the new error?